# How to correctly pass useState when calling async functions ? Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setfunctions is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am populating a table of data pulled from a firebase firestore database. I am using the useState hook which I love, however I am coming across an error when trying to pass useState to my async method.

Any ideas?

```
// My async function
const collectionGroupGet = async (setfunctions) => {
    let functionsArray = [];

  var functions = db.collectionGroup("Functions");
  functions.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        functionsArray.push({ data: doc.data() });
        setfunctions(functionsArray);
    });
  });

};

// My functional component
const ExpFirestore = () => {
 const [functions, setfunctions] = useState("");
 collectionGroupGet(setfunctions)

 ... other irrelevant code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information here to be certain what the issue is, but you should be doing your `async` stuff in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) function.  Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-rgb-f3r4f?file=/src/App.js) of passing a `useState` set method to an `async` function during render.  Hope that helps!  If you provide more information or a sandbox that reproduces the issue I can update the answer to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate it.